# How to access data in an iteration when reading a csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that I cannot solve.
I would like to be able to do the following when reading a csv

At each iteration, I can access a column by its name from the csv

I tried the following code but was unsuccessful

```
products = pandas.read_csv(f'./storage/temp/{file_name}', delimiter=',', on_bad_lines='skip').to_dict()
        
        for index, product in products:
            print(product.product_url)
```

csv example data

```
product_url,image_url,categories,attributes,description,product_name,reviews,stock,sku,product_gift,price,price_with_discount,categories_urls
http://localhost:8000/?product=aw-bellies,http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/red-as-454-aw-11-original-imaeebfwsdf6jdf6-324x324.jpeg,Footwear,"""[{""""Ideal For"""":""""Women""""}","{""""Occasion"""":""""Casual""""}","{""""Color"""":""""Red""""}]""","""Key Features of AW Bellies Sandals Wedges Heel Casuals",AW Bellies Price: Rs. 499 Material: Synthetic Lifestyle: Casual Heel Type: Wedge Warranty Type: Manufacturer Product Warranty against manufacturing defects: 30 days Care instructions: Allow your pair of shoes to air and de-odorize at regular basis; use shoe bags to prevent any stains or mildew; dust any dry dirt from the surface using a clean cloth; do not use polish or shiner,"Specifications of AW Bellies General Ideal For Women Occasion Casual Shoe Details Color Red Outer Material Patent Leather Heel Height 1 inch Number of Contents in Sales Package Pack of 1 In the Box One Pair Of Shoes""","""AW Bellies""",,1,2,,499,499,http://localhost:8000/?product_cat=footwear
```

For example, I would like all these data when I access them from csv in a for loop
To access them, for example, like this

```
for product in products:
   print(product.product_url)
```

I can't access the column because it doesn't exist (I don't think it sees it as a dictionary)

Comment: Edit the question to explain what happens, what should happen.

Comment: No. (1) The last code sample is syntactically incorrect (the `'`). (2) What is the output or error message that happens, what is the expected output (show it as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Do you just want to extract one value from each row and from the same column at load time? If the answer is yes, pandas is overkill and you'd better use the standard library `csv` module: it can return one row at a time, either as a list or as a dict indexed by the column names.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use pandas for this purpose.

```
import pandas as pd

products = pd.read_csv('dffile.txt', header=0)


print(products['product_url'])

for i in products.columns:
    print('name column', i)
    print(products[i])
```

But, if you still need it, as you tried, then you need to apply items ().

```
file_name = 'dffile.txt'

products = pd.read_csv(f'{file_name}', delimiter=',', on_bad_lines='skip').to_dict()


for k, v in products.items():
    print('kay', k)
    print('value', v)
```